# Send email from G-Sheets after 4 weeks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am using Google Sheets, and I'm trying to send an email to myself, after 4 weeks of a specified date, with information in the body of that email extracted from a certain cell. The cell is in the same row (Col B) that the date is in (Col Q). I have successfully figured out the timing issue, but I just can't get the info from the cell to go into the body of the email.

Here is the code I have.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(9,17,31).getValues();
  var now = Date.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[0]);
    var remind_date = new Date(date.getTime() + 28 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var diff = now - remind_date;
    var case_name = row[2];
if ((diff >= 0) && (diff < 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail('myemail@me.com', 'Case Inquiry Reminder','Reminder, inquire about status of ', case_name);
    }

      }
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't include enough details. What values are data getting? Do you get an error message? Have you tried the debugger tool? See [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting).

Comment: Most of the values are dates, and 'case_name' is a text string like "Johnson File". I don't get an error, the information just doesn't show up in the resulting email. I've been using logs to check what values get returned, and it lists 'case_name' as "undetermined"

Answer (score 0):

## First part

On the question it's mentioned that the date is on column Q but the code is getting column A instead.

`var date = new Date(row[0]);`

Maybe the correct code is

`var date = new Date(row[16]);`

While some Spreadsheet Service methods use 1 based index, JavaScript arrays use zero based index. Because of this, the index of column Q is 16.

## Second part

For the same reason mentioned previously regarding JavaScript indexes, as you said that you need the value of column B, instead of

`var case_name = row[2];`

the code should be

`var case_name = row[1];`

Reference

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

## Third part

There is a problem on the following line

`GmailApp.sendEmail('myemail@me.com', 'Case Inquiry Reminder','Reminder, inquire about status of ', case_name);`

It uses four arguments but the the fourth isn't of the proper type. Maybe you intend to write

`GmailApp.sendEmail('myemail@me.com', 'Case Inquiry Reminder','Reminder, inquire about status of ' + case_name);`

(replace the last comma `,` by a plus sign `+`)

Reference

[sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options)

Comment: Thanks Reuben, this was really helpful. What I found out was that the first part only worked when I wrote it with no number index, like `var date = new Date(row);` I still can't get the email to refer to the cell in ColB, it always comes back as 'undefined'. Is it possible that it can't reference anything outside of the first range I set up '.getrange(9,17,31);' Should I 'get' another range?

Comment: @JohnB without more details I'm only able to guess what is happening. By example, I don't know if the date values are being getting as date or as strings. Consider to create a demo spreadsheet, share it with anyone with the link for viewing only and add the link to the question.

Comment: @JohnB Regarding the question in your comment you are right, you can't use array indexes to refer anything out of the array but I don't understand how this apply to the OP.